# How to find the message content of what was replied to in Discord [Discord.js]

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a simple piece of code that logs the message content whenever a message is sent. However, if the message is a reply to another message, it will only output what the reply was, and not the content of the original message as well.

```
client.on('message', async message => {
    console.log(message.content);
});
```

[image: image of the test input]
[image: image of the test output]

The output will be: test 4. How can I also extract test 3?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you receive the message object, you have a variable named `reference`.
If your message is a reply reference should not be null and contains the ids of `channelID`, `guildID`, `messageID`.

With this you can then get the message content of the previous message with a line that looks like

```js
client.on('message', async message => {
  const repliedTo = await message.channel.messages.fetch(message.reference.messageID);

  console.log(repliedTo.content);
});
```

Just be careful with the `message.reference.messageID` you have to add error handling to avoid crash when looking for an undefined variable.

Have a nice day