# Gettting the original content of message replied to. [discord.js]

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Picture this. someone sent a message(a). And i replied(b) to that with the bot command.
How would the bot be able to get the content of (a) from my reply(b)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the message content of what was replied to in Discord \[Discord.js\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65164329/how-to-find-the-message-content-of-what-was-replied-to-in-discord-discord-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the [`reference`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v12/class/Message?scrollTo=reference).

```js
//msg is an instance of Message
const reply = msg.reference;
const repliedTo = await msg.channel.messages.fetch(reply.messageID);
//repliedTo is the message object of the replied message
```

v13 however does have a [`fetchReference()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=fetchReference) function to easily do it.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the documentation I think [this](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=fetchReference) is what you're looking for, hope this helps :)
Example:

```
<Message>.fetchReference().then(msg => console.log(msg.content))
```

Comment: I'm getting an error stating that message.fetchReference is not a function....